# modifying the page header

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,10pt, twoside]{scrbook}%

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}                         
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}          
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\l@section[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.1em \@plus\p@
    \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}{\normalfont #1}{\normalfont #2}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.5em \@plus\p@
     \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1em}{\large #1}{\large #2}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \newcommand*\l@problem[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.1em \@plus\p@
    \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}{\normalfont #1}{\normalfont #2}
    }
\makeatother


\usepackage[noindentafter, pagestyles, explicit, extramarks]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \sethead[\thepage ][][\chaptername \, \thechapter.  \chaptertitle]% even
          {\ifthesection{\thesection \, \sectiontitle }{\theproblem \, \problemtitle}}{}{\thepage}} % odd

%chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}{\vspace{75pt}\Large} {\makebox[25 pt]{\raggedright\thechapter}}{8pt}{\hspace*{-6pt}\raggedright\Large #1}[\vspace{0.3pc} {\titlerule[3.5pt]} \vspace{50pt}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0 pt}{0 pt}{0 pt}[0 pt]

%section    
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\makebox[20 pt]{\large\thesection}}{15 pt}{#1} 
\titlespacing{\section}{-35 pt}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}

%problem 
\newcounter {problem}[chapter]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand {\theproblem}{P. \thechapter.\@arabic\c@problem}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\problemtitle}{}

\titleclass{\problem}{straight}[\chapter]        
\titleformat{name=\problem}{\large }{\makebox[25 pt]{\large\theproblem}}{15 pt}{#1}[]
\titlespacing{name=\problem}{-40 pt}{4ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{This is the first section}
\lipsum[2-20]
\problem{This is the first problem}
\lipsum[20-30]
\section{This is the second section}
\lipsum[2-10]


\end{document}
```

I'd like to modify the header on page number seven and to put something like `\theproblem \problemtitle` because I have defined a new sectioning command `problem`. I do not know how it is possible.

Comment: Please reduce your example to a real minimal working example. There are a lot of irrelevant commands.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, thanks for your comment. I have reduced the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you well. Search for `% NEW CONTENT START`/`% NEW CONTENT END` below:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,10pt, twoside]{scrbook}%

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}                         
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4em}          
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\l@section[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.1em \@plus\p@
    \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}{\normalfont #1}{\normalfont #2}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.5em \@plus\p@
     \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1em}{\large #1}{\large #2}
    }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \newcommand*\l@problem[2]
    {
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 0.1em \@plus\p@
    \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}{\normalfont #1}{\normalfont #2}
    }
\makeatother


\usepackage[noindentafter, pagestyles, explicit, extramarks]{titlesec}

%chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}{\vspace{75pt}\Large} {\makebox[25 pt]{\raggedright\thechapter}}{8pt}{\hspace*{-6pt}\raggedright\Large #1}[\vspace{0.3pc} {\titlerule[3.5pt]} \vspace{50pt}]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0 pt}{0 pt}{0 pt}[0 pt]

%section    
\titleformat{\section}{\large}{\makebox[20 pt]{\large\thesection}}{15 pt}{#1} 
\titlespacing{\section}{-35 pt}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}

%problem 
\newcounter {problem}[chapter]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theproblem}{P. \thechapter.\@arabic\c@problem}
\let\problemtitle\@empty
\makeatother

\titleclass{\problem}{straight}[\chapter]
% NEW CONTENT START
\titleformat{name=\problem}{\large }{\makebox[25 pt]{\large\theproblem}}{15 pt}{#1\gdef\problemtitle{#1}}[]
% NEW CONTENT START
\titlespacing{name=\problem}{-40 pt}{4ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{3ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}

% NEW CONTENT START
% page styles
\newpagestyle{chapter}{
    \sethead%
        [\thepage][][\chaptername \, \thechapter. \chaptertitle]% even
        {}{}{\thepage}% odd
    }
\newpagestyle{section}{
    \sethead%
        [\thepage][][\chaptername \, \thechapter. \chaptertitle]% even
        {\thesection \, \sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}% odd
    }
\newpagestyle{problem}{
    \sethead%
        [\thepage][][\chaptername \, \thechapter. \chaptertitle]% even
        {\theproblem \, \problemtitle}{}{\thepage}% odd
    }
\makeatletter
\let\chapter@without@pagestyle\chapter
\def\chapter{\pagestyle{chapter}\chapter@without@pagestyle}
\let\section@without@pagestyle\section
\def\section{\pagestyle{section}\section@without@pagestyle}
\let\problem@without@pagestyle\problem
\def\problem{\pagestyle{problem}\problem@without@pagestyle}
\makeatother

% NEW CONTENT END

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents

% NEW CONTENT START
\pagestyle{empty}

\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{This is the first section}
\lipsum[2-20]
\problem{This is the first problem}
\lipsum[20-30]
\section{This is the second section}
\lipsum[2-15]
\section{This is the third section}
\lipsum[16]
\problem{This is the second problem}
\lipsum[17]
% NEW CONTENT END

\end{document}
```

The result is following:

- Chapter 1 is defined on page 3. Thus, no section/problem-related header is present on odd pages since page 3 (effectively on page 5).
- Section 1.1 is defined on page 6. Thus, section-related header is added to odd pages since page 6 (effectively on page 7).
- Problem 1.1 is defined on page 9. Thus, problem-related header is added to odd pages since page 9 (effectively on page 9).
- Section 1.2 is defined on page 11. Thus, section-related header is added to odd pages since page 6 (effectively on page 11).
- Section 1.3 is defined on page 13. Thus, section-related header is added to odd pages since page 13 (effectively nowhere).
- Problem 1.2 is defined on page 13. Thus, problem-related header is added to odd pages since page 13 (effectively on page 13).

Concluding, `\chapter` cancels the odd-page header. It is then set again by both `\section` and `\problem`, whatever comes later.

Comment: Yes, you have understood the question but I think it is not answered well. The headers on page 3-10 are good but the header on page 11 is "P 1.1" and it should be "P 1.1 The first problem". The same situation on page 13. Thanks

Comment: In the MWE you've supplied you rely on `\problemtitle` which is not defined automatically AFAIK. You can define it, e.g., by putting `\gdef\problemtitle{#1}` into `\titleformat{name=\problem}` definition. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Perfect! I am going to vote up. Thanks again